# php directory iterator, shuffle images

Tags: php

```
<?php


$dir = new DirectoryIterator('../images/main_body_image/');
foreach ($dir as $file)
{
    $images [] = array (
    $file->getPathname() . "\n";
    $file->getFilename(). "\n";
    );
}

?>

shuffle($images);
```

Can you help me with the code above? I want to add images to an array using DirectoryIterator, and then shuffle images to generate randomized images. Thank you for your valuable inputs.

Comment: Besides a few syntax errors, your code seems to be on the right track. Where exactly do you need help?

Comment: This is all you need then: `if ($file->isFile()) $images [] = $file->getPathname();` also your code `shuffle($images);` should be before the closing `?>`

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you are doing with the images, and what path your in at the time, but the following will put their full pathname into an Array.

```
<?php
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('../images/main_body_image/');
foreach($dir as $file){
  $images[] = $file->getPathname();
}
shuffle($images); $imgs = '';
foreach($images as $v){
  $imgs .= "<img scr='http://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}/$v' alt='randomImage' />";
}
//put the below wherever you want in your code
echo $imgs;
?>
```

Comment: Don't forget to exclude `.` and `..` I don't think you would like an image like `<img src=".">` or `<img src="..">`

Comment: I'm assuming it's a folder full of Images otherwise I thing `glob()` makes more sense.

Comment: I want to display images randomly. it's currently showing pathnames, not the images themselves, do we need to include getFilename()?

Comment: `getFileName()` would work if your PHP page was in the same location as the images.

Comment: Have tried but your code isn't working properly; images aren't apparent at the browser.